# Is there a way to create a stored procedure in a database when you don't have permissions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions

From a security perspective, I'm curious to know if there is a way to create a stored procedure without permissions? For example, the following error is returned when tried `"CREATE PROCEDURE permission denied in database"`.

I'd like to see if there is a clever work around that can be applied. I understand this is a long shot but figured I'd gather ideas.

Comment: Why dont you use correct means and get the access, there must be some reason you are denied access.

Comment: Do you mean a way to provide elevated permissions to create procs in the application space or a way to circumvent lack of permissions for your own account? A work-around in the later case would be a hack, literally.

Comment: I think my question will give the impression that I'm trying to do something malicious. The reality is that people with permissions are out of the office. I can request to be granted permissions and then wait as the bureaucratic process decides whether to give me permissions. I need my changes in now. I'm looking for clever solutions not a twiddle my fingers approach.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. What you are looking for is called an Anonymous Procedure. As long as you don't need to permanently store your procedure (i.e. you just want to run it ad hoc), you can actually run T-SQL code this way.

See related https://stackoverflow.com/a/10818490/1680777
and http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/2167/what-is-anonymous-block

If you are looking to have a persistent procedure that can be called from multiple clients, you are probably out of luck on this one.

Ask your DBA for more privileges. If your DBA won't give you the permissions to CREATE PROCEDURE, then follow your organization's change process to get your proposed Stored Proc deployed. I know you already know this, since you're looking for an immediate & clever workaround and the admins are unavailable.  If only very few people can admin these systems, and they can possibly all be out at the same time, that's more of a human resource management problem.

You may be able to use this incident to campaign for process change with things that management like to hear, such as "if things were different and we had a Self-Service Access Management flow, I would have been able to fix that issue we had on June 30 much quicker."  Just saying that pain is often the precursor of important changes that would otherwise flounder in a bureaucratic workplace.  The worse you can paint the current state, the better.